# How to determine the currently active USB configuration with libusb 0.1

Tags: c, usb, libusb

How can I find out which USB configuration of a USB device is the current active one? I use libusb 0.1 (Not the newer 1.0 because I need libusb-win32) and there is only a usb_set_configuration() function but no usb_get_configuration(). Maybe the configuration value of the active configuration can be read from some descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, libusb-win32 curiously doesn't export such a method. However, there's a USB request for that, and you can easily make it yourself -- just scroll to line 106 in [libusb-win32/src/windows.c](http://libusb-win32.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libusb-win32/trunk/libusb/src/windows.c?revision=367&view=markup).

Basically, this is what you want to do:

```
#define LIBUSB_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT 5000

char config;
int ret = usb_control_msg(dev, USB_RECIP_DEVICE | USB_ENDPOINT_IN,
                      USB_REQ_GET_CONFIGURATION, 0, 0, &config, 1,
                      LIBUSB_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: No, these are different values. As far as I know bConfigurationValue is the identifier of the configuration, the value I have to specify to activate this specific configuration. And iConfiguration is a string descriptor index which describes the configuration descriptor.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Of course you're right. I got confused for a moment there :) I've changed my answer -- see above.